# ∅ ⊆ { ∅ } Is this true or false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

True or false? Im guessing true because an empty set is a subset of every set. Is this a correct assumption? The only time an empty set is not a subset of something is when its a proper subset of an empty set correct?

Comment: There is never a case when the empty set is not a subset of a given set.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have one more question regarding an empty set. How is ∅ proper subset { ∅ } true?

Comment: True. Ask yourself what element in the empty set is not in the set containing the empty set as an element?

Comment: The only set $A$ such that $\emptyset$ is not a proper subset of $A$ is $\emptyset$.

Comment: @user2743857: Check the definition of proper subset.  Compare the elements of the two sets.  Which part isn't clear?

Comment: Yes. The reason the empty set is a proper subset is because the empty set doesn't contain the element "the empty set."

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. Really helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\varnothing \subset A$ for **any** set $A$, including $ A  = \{\varnothing \}$.

Suppose there is a set $A$ such that $\varnothing \not\subset A$. Then exists $x \in \varnothing$ such that $x \not\in A$. But this is a contradiction, because there is no element in $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to assume anything is true.  You can easily show this is true.  Let $x \in \emptyset$.  Since there is no such $x$, all statements about $x$ are perforce true, including $x \in \{\emptyset\}$.  So $\emptyset \subset  \{\emptyset\}$.